# Toggling Radio Buttons with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle a couple of radio buttons using jQuery. But it is turning out to be not so simple.

```
<button id="toggler">click me</button><br>
<input type="radio" name="speeds" value="fast" checked>fast<br>
<input type="radio" name="speeds" value="slow">slow<br>

$('#toggler').click(function() {
    $('input[name="speeds"]').each(function(){
        $(this).prop("checked", !$(this).prop("checked"));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/beC7q/

Could anyone please explain why the code above does not work?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If there are only two radio buttons

```
$('#toggler').click(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').prop("checked", true);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Wz5BA/)

If there are more than 2 elements

```
var $radios = $('input[type="radio"][name="speeds"]')
$('#toggler').click(function() {
    var $checked = $radios.filter(':checked');
    var $next = $radios.eq($radios.index($checked) + 1);
    if(!$next.length){
        $next = $radios.first();
    }
    $next.prop("checked", true);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Wz5BA/2/)

Answer (score 9):

Radio buttons in a group (i.e., `input`s with the same `name` value) are already mutually exclusive. You only need to modify the "checked" state of one to change the entire group's state:

This code, for example, would always set the last radio in the group to "checked":

```
$('#toggler').click(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"][name="speeds"]').last().prop('checked', true);
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/beC7q/7/)</kbd>