# Make Input Radio work inside <a href>

Tags: wordpress, input, hyperlink, radio-button, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to make tabbed comments section for WordPress. I use jQuery UI tabs to make it work. I have styled radio switches between  tags but it does not works. When I click a tab, link click happens and radio button does not change.

my code for first `<li>` element looks like this:

```
<li class="active ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" id="comments-evolved-Facebook-control" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="comments-evolved-Facebook-tab" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <a href="#comments-evolved-Facebook-tab" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">
        <div class="switch switch-Facebook">
            <input name="multicomments" id="Facebook-toggle" class="switch-control" type="radio">
            <label class="switch-toggle" for="Facebook-toggle">
                <div class="switch-handle"><span><i class="icon-multicommentsFacebook"></i></span>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div><span id="comments-evolved-Facebook-label">Label Example</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

see actual WordPress page: [Page with comments](http://dbcnews.ga/test-page-for-comments)

Comment: You might need to do a onclick jquery/javascript to toggle the radio button. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141911/toggling-radio-buttons-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Here is the jQuery code I added.

```
jQuery('#".$tab."').click(function() {
   jQuery('#".$tab."-toggle').prop('checked', true);
});

`".$tab."` is the `<li>` element ID
```